# C# MongoDB driver strongly typed filter usage

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The documentation tells you how to define a filter, but not how to use it.

```
public class Widget : BsonDocument
{
    [BsonElement("X")]
    public int X { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Y")]
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public MyItem Get()
{
    MyItem retvalue = null;

    var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Eq("x", 10) & builder.Lt("y", 20);
    Console.WriteLine(_collection.Count(filter));

    var builder2 = Builders<Widget>.Filter;
    var filter2 = builder2.Eq(widget => widget.X, 10) & builder2.Lt(widget => widget.Y, 20);
    Console.WriteLine(_collection.Count(filter2));

    return retvalue;
}
```

So the first filter is working - but it is **not** strongly typed.

The second filter cannot be used like that.
Compiler error: **cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition' to 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition'**

So the question is - how do I use this as a filter. Obviously the filter parameter is defined as FilterDefinition. Deriving MyItem from BsonDocument didn't help. "`filter2.ToBsonDocument()`" compiles but doesn't yield the correct result (filter is not working!).

Can someone point me into the right direction?
And some place I can read about that?

Comment: what driver version is in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will suggest to use as querable which is handy approach to manipulate queries.

```
  _result = _collection.AsQueryable().First(w => w.X == x && w.Y < y);
```

or using expression filter definition

```
_result = _collection
           .Find(new ExpressionFilterDefinition<Widget>
               (widget => widget.X == 10 && widget.Y < y))
           .First()
```

full version on [github](https://github.com/profesor79/SOSolver/blob/master/SoQuestionsSolver/SoQuestionsSolver/StronglyTypedFilterUsageSteps.cs)

c# driver reference [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to ExpressionFilterDefinition. That works. Also I'm not sure if I had _database.GetCollection*<Widget>* before